# Arc segment of length 1, segment's Y-coordinate & circle's center Y-coordinate: return arc segment's X-coordinate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Given:

- A circle's arc segment of length = 1, and the Y-coordinate of its endpoint
- The Y-coordinate of the circle's center
- The fact that the circle goes through the origin: (0,0)

Is it possible to find the X-coordinate of the arc segment's endpoint?

I refer to the image below:

[image]

The arc segment is the thick blue segment on the black dotted circle: its length is 1, the horizontal coordinate of its endpoint is marked by the upper dotted blue line, and the blue dot on the Y-axis. The circle center's vertical coordinate is the bottom blue dotted line, and the required coordinate is the red dot on the X-axis, marked by a red dotted line: this is what I am looking for.

Much obliged!

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before applying them: this is not the first time you've tagged an elementary problem involving both algebra and geometry as algebraic-geometry, which the tag expressly mentions is inappropriate. I've retagged as analytic-geometry, which is much more appropriate for this question.

Comment: 3 unknowns and 3 equations - could you get them? Could you solve them?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

According the diagram, the following can be established,

$$\theta r = 1,\>\>\>\>\>b=r\sin(\pi-\theta),\>\>\>\>\>-x=r+r\cos(\pi-\theta)$$

which lead to,

$$x=-b\tan\frac\theta2,\>\>\>\>\>b=\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$$

Eliminate θ to obtained the equation

$$\tan^{-1}\frac xb = \frac x{b^2+x^2}$$

Therefore, the $x$-coordinate of the endpoint can be obtained if $b$, the $y$-coordinate of the endpoint is known.